# Why are the values returned from getFloatFrequencyData negative?

Tags: javascript, fft, microphone, getusermedia, web-audio-api

I want to take input from microphone and pass it to the analyser node to extract the frequency data. I explored *Web Audio Api* and *GetUserMedia* for sometime but could not figure out why all the values in the console are **negative**. Shouldn't there be positive values as well ? What is the significance of these negative values?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video:false}).then(function(stream){               
              aContext = new AudioContext();
              analyser = aContext.createAnalyser();
              microphone = aContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
              microphone.connect(analyser);
              analyser.connect(aContext.destination);
              LoopFunc();
          });                    

     var LoopFunc = function (){
          setInterval(function(){
              frequencyData = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
              analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(frequencyData);
              console.log(frequencyData);                  
          },100);
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

from [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#widl-AnalyserNode-getFloatFrequencyData-void-Float32Array-array)

> `getFloatFrequencyData`
>
> Copies the current frequency data into the passed floating-point array. If the array has fewer elements than the frequencyBinCount, the excess elements will be dropped. If the array has more elements than the frequencyBinCount, the excess elements will be ignored.
>
> **The frequency data are in dB units.**

which then leads to the question: [What does negative numbers on the decibel scale mean?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-negative-numbers-on-the-decibel-scale-mean)